# How to use Google Analytic custom dimension?

Tags: google-analytics

I have read some google analytic custom dimension explanations but still can't find a tutorial that explains the steps from beginning to end. I know many have discussed this but many tutorials are incomplete and jumping from the side of the settings in Google Analytics and from the side of laying the code in the project makes me confused.
What I have done,
First I add custom dimension from admin->custom definition->custom dimension
[image]

Then, I create a custom report from customization for showing my custom dimension
[image]

Then, I put the javascript code in my project

```
<script>
  var test = 'test';
  ga('create', 'UA-11xxxxxx', 'auto')
  ga('set', 'dimension1', test);
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

But, If open the custom report it always returning no data(I have waiting more than a day but still no data)
[image]

Is there something wrong with what I've done or are there any steps that were missed?

Any helps will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This might be a reporting problem (as you are using a user level dimension with hit level metrics). The code looks fine.